# How to scrape text from http://shinytoylabs.com/jargon/ using python

Tags: python, html, forms

How can i scrape generated text from http://shinytoylabs.com/jargon/ using python? I want to use python requests or something like that but not selenium. The problem is that i cannot use simple POST or GET request as this page doesn't use POST nor GET form. There is just one button which you click and it generates text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i would do this !

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://shinytoylabs.com/jargon/")
generateButton = driver.find_element_by_class_name("generate-button")
generateButton.click()
textToCopy = driver.find_element_by_class_name("jargon-output-container")
print(textToCopy.text)
```

you need to `pip install selenium` and download chrome webdriver from [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.37/)
and add the downloaded driver path in system PATH environment variable.
I have tested it, works fine for me with chrome browser.

Comment: But i dont want to use selenium as this opens browser window :( I want it to happen in background.